# Youtube V3 API : know if the video is avaliable on Android mobile device

Tags: android, youtube-api

Recently I retrieve the information of videos which should be played on the Android apps with Youtbe V3 API. The problem is some of them are not avaliable on the mobile device. And I found no related property according to the document. Is it possible for me to filter out those videos? Or should I add any header within http request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two concepts embeddable and syndicated.
iOS devices use iframe so they basically embed. 
Android devices that use player API can check syndicated.

When you do a [search->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), you can set [videoEmbeddable](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoEmbeddable) and [videoSyndicated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoSyndicated) to true.

Or if you are iterating through videos, for each video, you can do a [video->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call with video id and check [status.embeddable](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.embeddable) in the response.

Here is a [blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html) about this topic, even though examples are in v2, information is still relevant.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it is ok for me thant the videos are not embeddable as I just need to play them on Youtube APP. The problem is that they can't be played on mobile device.

Comment: Yeah `videoSyndicated` is what I want. Thanks!

Comment: When using `video->list` is there a way of getting a value for `videoSyndicated`?