# YouTubePlayer doesn't work for some videos

Tags: android, youtube-api

i am using YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar in my android application so i can read youtube videos.

This is working fine for most videos. I am getting error (No valid request) only when the video id contain a special letter like #.

I am getting the problem for this video for exemple:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/eg1Jb_mSQZQ#t=0

The video exist on youtube site but i can't read it in my android device.

```
@Override
  public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
      boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
      player.cueVideo(id);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "#" in the Youtube URL (or any URL for that matter) is called an anchor, and is used to pass extra parameters to the page.  The YouTube ID is everything before that anchor.

So in your example, the actual YouTube ID would be "eg1Jb_mSQZQ".

Answer (score 0):

Besides the "#" parameter not all videos in YouTube website will play in Android or other platforms.

Here's my previous answer. [Youtube V3 API : know if the video is avaliable on Android mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001251/youtube-v3-api-know-if-the-video-is-avaliable-on-android-mobile-device/17004800#17004800)