# Exclude restricted videos from youtube query Using YouTube API

Tags: ios, video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm developing an iOS application that fetches some Youtube videos. I'm using this YouTube API:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=xxxxx&v=2
And here is the link of YouTube documentations [YouTube Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters)
I play the videos using [YouTube Helper Library iOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) , (which is designed for playing Youtube videos)

I searched the documentation many times looking for a way to customize the results,
**I need to exclude the restricted videos like the VEVO channel video or any other 
restricted video for any channel**, *because regrading to YouTube Helper Library limitations 
they do not allow to play these videos ..*

How can I exclude these videos using Youtube API ?
If I can't do that using this API, is there any way to achieve that using different API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GData API is going away](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2015/03/dude-are-you-still-on-youtube-api-v2.html).

You can do this in v3 by: [Youtube V3 API : know if the video is avaliable on Android mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001251/youtube-v3-api-know-if-the-video-is-avaliable-on-android-mobile-device/17004800#17004800)